# React js CRUD - How to automatically update table when adding data without refreshing

Tags: reactjs

I am creating CRUD for my react js application, basically what happen is when I added or post a data it will be added but the table will not update or show the latest data that is added unless you refresh the page.

Here is my code for displaying the data

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://mylink')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({students: response.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('No data to be shown')
        })
    }
```

And for adding data

```
handleAddData = () => {
axios({
          url: 'http://mylink',
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data: {
            students: students
          }
        })
```

What i want to happen is when the data is added the table will automatically update without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Posts are usually made with one new element, and you update the state's students when confirmed:

```js
axios({
    url: 'http://mylink',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: newStudent // must receive this

 })
.then( response => {
    const { students } = this.state;
    this.setState({students: [newStudent, ...students});
})
```

Be aware that if you expect to received the updated version of the new student from the back-end you should add the very response to the list:

```js
.then( response => {
    const { students } = this.state;
    const confirmation = response.data;
    this.setState({students: [confirmation, ...students});
})
```